# Why .net 3.5 WPF Application not running in some Win 10 OS

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-10

I created some simple **.NET 3.5 WPF application** using **visual studio 2008** (Win 7 OS). My PC win 10 verion is 1709 (OS Build 16299.251). But that application ***can't running on some win 10 OS***. (It's working perfeclty on win 7 and some of win 10 pc/laptop).  By the way .NET 3.5 C# application working all above pc/laptop.  I re-installed .NET 3.5 but it's not working. And update all drivers those pc/laptop.

**EDIT**

The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Media.FontFamily' threw an exception. when I tried to build that application in Win 10 PC(error came on that pc). But this application perfectly builds in Win 7 and some Win 10 PC.

Comment: Is flag ".NET Framework 3.5" checked in "Programs and Components → Turn Windows Features on or off"?

Comment: Already did it. But It's not working @N.Kudryavtsev

Comment: Did you uncheck it, restart and then check it and restart again?

I have had issues with some W10 computers (not all) that do not seem to install all of .NET3.5 in the control panel (try it first though) and when I ran the offline installer (https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=25150) it started working.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Load the app in VS2017 and use debugger to see what fails.

Comment: Thank you @magicandre1981. That error resolved. That error came from the font. I removed special fonts and then it's working.

Comment: which font was it?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Sinhala font. It's my primary language font(Sri Lanka).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So 'can't run' is quite wide spread.

As you mentioned that .Net Framework 3.5 is already installed and you tried reinstalling it (hopefully by control panel - as mentioned by Kudryavtsev), it may be that the application is crashing directly in front.

Please open the event viewer (control panel -> administrative tools -> event viewer) and check in the Application area for '.Net Runtime Errors'.

**EDIT**

The real error (see comment section):

**The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Media.FontFamily' threw an exception.**  when I tried to build that application in Win 10 PC(error came on that pc). But this application perfectly builds in Win 7 and some Win 10 PC.

The resolution was to remove some 'special fonts' from the application

Comment: There are no any errors. When I open the application, It's running background, but not visible forms.

Comment: The crash should be there - equal if it is running in background or foreground. What do you mean by background? As a windows service? If yes and you just double click the executable what error do you receive?

Comment: Sry Background means when I open application Its showing task list in task manager, but not visible forms.

Comment: Do you have any special code in your form loaded event? Can you see it in the task area? If yes, is it possible that it is somewhere outside of the screen bounds? Tried with maximized state at startup?

Comment: No, it's just only one form with one button. no any event with the loaded event. Very simple application for testing.

Comment: <b>The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Media.FontFamily' threw an exception. </b> when I tried to build that application in Win 10 PC(error came on that pc). But this application perfectly builds in Win 7 and some Win 10 PC.

Comment: This error happened to us when we used Glyphs - and on some machines the windir environmental variable was set incorrectly. Also on citrix environments where the user had limited permissions. Are you setting a special font for your application?  The full exception stack trace would be helpfull - eg. the innerexception details.

Comment: Thank you @dsdel. That error resolved. That error came from the font. I removed special fonts and then it's working.

Comment: @Ayesh, please be so kind to select my answer as solution - Thank you!